# back button in listView causes crash

Tags: android

I have an editText and button. Push the button, it launches a listView activity. Click on an item in the listView, it closes that activity and sets the editText to the item that was clicked on.

But if you get to the listView and hit the back button with clicking an item, it crashes. I think I need to do something in onPause but not sure if that's the best way to go about it.

listView, when item clicked...

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("TEXT", ((TextView) view).getText().toString());
            intent.putExtras(b);
            setResult(SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE, intent);
            finish();
```

onActivityResult....

```
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            mEditCategory.setText(b.getString("TEXT"));
```

Comment: If you get a crash, then you have a log with a full stack trace. You need to post that.

Comment: I don't see anything in the log. But if I remove Bundle b = data.getExtras(); from onActivityResult, it doesn't crash but it doesn't work when you select an item then.

Comment: If it crashes, you will definitely have a full callstack and the error message.

Comment: There's nothing I can make sense of in there. Doesn't the fact that if I remove that one line, it doesn't crash give a good idea of what the error is? I'm pretty sure that the click listener isn't getting triggered which means nothing is being put into b.

Comment: Does `data` have a valid value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an exception: `data` is `null` because your activity did not return a result.

By default, the back key will end the activity without setting a result. Check the `resultCode` parameter to `onActivityResult` to see whether the sub-activity returned because the list item was clicked:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE) {
        // TODO handle data here from list item click
    }
}
```

The `resultCode` will be `RESULT_CANCELED` if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation (see [docs for Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)).

Comment: Google documents this, but not well.  As Mike's example shows, you might as well check for success before continuing.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html#ReceiveResult